# display result from database from dropmenu in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a dropdown menu and when I click on the link I would like to go to the page view_products.php and there it should display all my products found in cat=B1. I would like to use jquery to load the result from the database into my #content, but I am completely stuck. I have tried to write a jquery script from looking at tutorials, but I really don’t know how to pass the cat variable to my get_content page. The php and mysql is no problem, just the jquery. Many thanks /linda

**nav.php**

```
<div>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="view_products.php?cat=B1">Item 1</li>
<li><a href="view_products.php?cat=C1">Item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**view_products.php**

```
include('include/header.php');
include('include/nav.php');

<div id="content"></div>

include('include/footer.php');
```

**get_content.php**

```
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
echo $cat;
```

**display_product.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // initial
  $('#content').load('get_content.php');

  $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#content').load('get_content.php', {cat:x});
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you write your syntax , the Post variable cannot be known with ajax load request , you can use $.post ajax request instead of it. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need jQuery/Ajax to do that? You can simply capture the category value using:

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
```

Then in your `content` container, you can run a query to pull records from the database

```
<div id="content">
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['cat']))
  {
     $cat = $_GET['cat'];  // will store 'B1', 'C1' etc

     // connect to DB
     // pull data from DB using $cat
     // display the data
  }
  ?>
</div>
```